# Hide one particle system using another particle system

Tags: particles

I want to put 5-10 2 ft disks on a plane of grass.

I want them to be randomly placed, so it makes the most sense for me to make each a single disk particle and apply it to my grass plane, so I can just change the seed and they'll be placed in new locations.

The problem is that my grass particles stick out of the disks, so I'm wondering what the best way is to hide the grass wherever a disk is placed?

Comment: Use geometry nodes with proximity...this can do it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with more steps? I am a beginner stil

Comment: i added an answer

Comment: So what was the outcome here @kevinlinxc - did you get it working?

Comment: Apologies. I just ended up making my "on top" particle thicker, since I was only looking from an eagle eye perspective and so it didn't matter. The example by Chris seems pretty good, I'll mark it as valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. instance some objects on e.g. a plane like this:

[image]

2. instance some bigger objects on that same plane with less density like this:

[image]

3. add these filter nodes which "subtract" the little objects from the big ones within a certain distance

[image]

[image]

and with a little math, you can have a nice falloff as well like this:

[image]